# How to use preposition "to" , infinitive "to" and "---ing"?

Tags: grammar

When I was taking my examination, I 'learned' a new word, but I don't know how to use it. I don't know if the *to* following the word is a preposition. If it is then I should say "to doing". Or if *to* is part of the infinitive infinitive - then I should say *to do*. In other words: "to do" or "doing": are there any rules?

For example in "*suggest doing something*" why not use an infinitive? Why do we tend to say "*object to doing*" rather than "*object to do*"? I am sorry that maybe there's something wrong with my expression - but I would be grateful if you would like to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Many prepositions usually come before a noun. We usually use the *--ing* form of verbs  after prepositions which come before nouns. Some examples of prepositions like this are: *in, on, at, about, of, up* and *to*. Here are some examples of sentences with prepositions plus *--ing*:

- I succeeded in passing my exams
- I am keen on dancing.
- I am good at cooking.
- I am mad about jogging.
- I tire of reading very quickly
- I gave up smoking.
- I object to working.

Some verbs about liking/enjoying activities and also not liking/not enjoying activities usually take --ing forms of the verb:

I like shopping
I hate shopping
I love shopping
I don't mind shopping
I enjoy shopping
I detest shopping
I loathe shopping
I adore shopping

Some other verbs also take --ing form. The best way to learn them is to learn the verbs in a sentence, not just as one word:

- I loathe shopping.

Sometimes we know that there is a *to* after a particular verb. We don't always know whether *to* is a preposition or whether it is part of another verb phrase, for example '*to swim*':

- want to [verb]
- object to [verb]

There is an easy way to test whether *to* is a preposition or part of another verb. We can use a noun after the verb that we want to test:

- I want **bananas**. (no *to*)
- I object to **bananas**. (still has *to*)

In the first example, the word *to* disappeared. This shows that it belongs to another verb. It belongs to an infinitive. When there is no verb after *want*, there is no *to*. In the example with *object*, we still have the word *to*. This shows that it is a preposition. We still use the preposition when it comes before a noun.

Now we know that *want* must be followed by *to + infinitive* and *object to* must be followed by *--ing* (because *to* here is a preposition):

- I want [to smoke].
- I object to [smoking].

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: +1. :) . . . But maybe if you could elaborate some more on this "test" for us? Because I haven't had no coffee yet and I don't expect to do no heavy thinking this early in the day (4 PM), and kinda wanna the grammar to be spoon fed to me. :)

Comment: @F.E.Will cogitate on bus home. In the meantime do you fancy casting a beady eye over [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211005/inversion-with-only-in-a-passive-sentence/211027#211027) I think the question might deserve a reopen vote ... Though what I really want is for someone to vet my answer ... :)

Comment: I thought it was pretty good when I had read it the other day :) -- (Hmm, it seems that I was the only one who upvoted your answer. That is kinda disappointing to see.)

Comment: @F.E. I don't think closed questions get that many views :) Don't mind really, but wasn't entirely sure if it was readable/accurate, so thanks! ...

Comment: @F.E. Re the 'test', well, yes, this is of my own devising from teaching. But is seems pretty straightforward unless I'm missing something (- entirely possible). Infinitival *to* clearly belongs to the infinitival VP, not the original verb. In your grammar, I'd assume that VP's headed by the verb in the infinitive. For me *to* heads the phrase. Anyhow, if the complement of the original verb is not a VP there'll be no infinitival *to*. If there's no subsequent verb phrase then certainly in H&P grammar, and probably in mine there can be no infinitival *to* if the complement isn't a verb ...

Comment: @F.E. ... On the other hand if the verb in question takes a preposition as a complement, then statistically the chances of that preposition taking an infinitival VP complement are miniscule. I only know of a handful of examples such as *about* in phrases like *about to leave*. I certainly don't know of any example where the preposition *to* can take an infinitive. If the preposition *to* is a dependent preposition of the original verb occurring before an *ing* verb form, then this preposition probably also takes a noun as complement ...

Comment: @F.E. ... In any case, if the verb can have a noun as complement, there's no reason for the dependent preposition *to* (i.e. it's complement) to disappear before a noun. The word(s) that follow the preposition are dependents of the preposition! So it's not going to disappear. There may well be a big hole in my reasoning. If you can find one, I'll post an interesting question with a huge bounty on it to reward you - cuz I've been telling that to students for years, so if I'm wrong I certainly need to know a.s.a.p.! :)

Comment: I've just started my first cup of coffee, and so, I wasn't really able to follow your last comments here. Perhaps if you posted them as a question-post on ELL, your test that is, and as a formatted rationale, I might be able to take a look. There probably is competition between those various constructions (e.g. 'to'-PP vs 'to'-infinitival, vs '-ing'-clause, 'for'-PP vs 'for'-infinitival, etc.). Be interesting to read something on it. :)

Comment: @Araucaria thanks a lot .i got it.you mean object here is intransitive verb,so it needs a prep,and i wanna ask these words like suggest,finish,are not expressing your feeling,so how could i know what kind of words belong to gerund or infinitive?

Answer (score 0):

By itself "to doing" is not a valid English construction. Sometimes, 'to V-ing' is part of a larger phrase. In the sentence "My boss is used to doing all the company's taxes," the full construction is "be used to V-ing."

It means the subject is accustomed to that activity. Other examples:

- I am used to swimming in the ocean.
- She is used to riding horses.
- They were used to holding garage sales in the fall.

An infinitive is only the word 'to' followed by the basic form of a verb: 'to do', 'to be', 'to go', etc.

Maybe you've heard of gerunds? Gerunds are a part of speech made up of -ing verbs (present participles) that we treat like nouns. Most activities are gerunds. In the sentence "I like cake," 'cake' is a noun. Although 'run' is a verb, in the sentence "I like running," 'running' is a noun.

In conversational English, when suggesting an activity, we might ask, "How about watching a movie?" instead of asking "Do you want to watch a movie?" In those questions, 'watch' is a verb, and 'watching' is an activity/gerund.

Comment: i'am appreciate your answer,the last point you mentioned is our biggest problem for we are influenced by our native language.and i wanna ask what kind of verb follow this pattern"v+to do"?what kind of verb follow"v+doing"

Comment: @miltonaut Could you change the *used to* example. It is usually confusing for learners because of the verb construction *used to*. Thanks! :)

Comment: Could you show us how "running" in "I like running" is a noun and not a verb? And could you show us whether "watching" is a noun or a verb in "How about watching a movie?", too?